Codimension of the non-smooth locus
Suppose $X$ is a variety (i.e. separated, finite type, reduced scheme) of pure dimension $d$ over a field $k$.
Then the locus of non-smooth points in $X$ is closed, as it is locally defined by the vanishing of the appropriate minors of the Jacobian of some $f_i\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ where $Spec(k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots, f_r))$ is an affine open in $X$.
I would like to show that the codimension of this non-smooth locus is $\geq 1$.
If $k$ is a non perfect field of characteristic $p$ and $\alpha\in k$ does not have a $p^{th}$ root in $k$, then $X_0^p-\alpha X_1^p$ is irreducible in $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ and all of its derivatives vanish. So it defines an irreducible variety of dimension $d=n-1$ in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ which has no smooth points.
To avoid this example, let's assume $k$ is perfect (or $X$ is geometrically reduced). So the question becomes:
QUESTION: Suppose $X$ is a variety of pure dimension $d$ over a field $k$. Assume $k$ is perfect (or $X$ is geometrically reduced, if that's enough).  Is the codimension in $X$ of the non-smooth locus $\geq 1$?
